# How to populate array in JS & React? TypeError: Cannot set property 'organisation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I want to populate the "data" array with the data I am receiving from "displayUserInfo". Not surprisingly the code snippet bellow only takes and records the last line of my input.

```
populateArray = () => {
    var index= 0;
    let data =  [{
        name: "",
        surname: "",
        age: ""
    }]

    this.state.displayUserInfo.map(currData => {

        data.name = currData.givenName;
        data.surname = currData.givenSurname;
        data.age = currData.givenAge;

        index++;
    });
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```

I would like to do somehting like this:

```
data[index].name = currData.givenName;
```

But it gives me error:
**TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined**

How can I have all the data from the input(Array of objects) mapped correctly to the "data" array? Is this method correct? Any other approaches? Thanks

Comment: You are setting value to `data` and not `data[index]`. Try `const data = this.state.displayUserInfo.map(( { givenName: name, givenSurname: surname: givenAge: age } ) => ( { name, surname, age  } ))`

Comment: Great! That worked. Any further explanation or it just the way to do it in this case? Thanks!